# LINQ To SQL Not Submitting Changes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

This seems like a popular question as I've seen several threads on this. However, I can't get updates to work. I have some LINQ-to-SQL code that looks like the following:

```
int orderID = GetOrderID();
using (DBDataContext database = new DBDataContext())
{
  var order = database.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderID == orderID);
  if (order != null)
  {
    order.IsOpen = GetIsOpen();
    database.SubmitChanges();
  }
}
```

I can set my breakpoint and see that it is getting into my IF statement. I've also fired up SQL profiler and have noticed that no statements are coming in for this code. Yet, I can successfully add Orders using the following code:

```
Order newOrder = GetNewOrder();
using (DBDataContext database = new DBDataContext())
{
    database.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(newOrder);
    database.SubmitChanges();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try having a try catch block and see if it is throwing any exception.

Comment: Do you have a PK on your table?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are hitting the correct database...if you manually change a property of an Order in the database then hit that break point...do you see what you expect.

Comment: Are you sure `IsOpen` actually changed? Is `GetIsOpen()` returning the same value that `IsOpen` already has? If it the value does not change then no update will take place. If it is changing the value then does your order class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and does the setter of `IsOpen` fire it?

Comment: Are you in a TransactionScope declared higher up? And: is IsOpen a database field? Or something you added manually?

Comment: @Villager Would be nice with some feedback after lots of people have suggested what to do

Answer (score -2):

I think you may need to mark the Order as changed by doing the following

```
database.MarkAsModified(order)
```

before database.SubmitChanges()

Comment: ok appreciated, but if IsOpen isnt actually being changed (as @Mike-Two suggested) or the generated class, for some unknown reason, isnt tracking changes then maybe this could help highlight the issue?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have to do that. Even if that would solve the problem (which it wont) then it does not fix the root cause as the entity should track changes

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest that the generated code was misbehaving. I was allowing for the possibility that there might not be generated code. You don't have to use the generator to use linq to sql.